# Probability of unknown distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, percentages

Say for instance you have 4 possible items of type $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ in a bag.
You know there are $100$ items in the bag. You don't know how many of each are in the bag. The items are not put back in the bag.

1. Am I correct in saying before you draw any out of the bag, the probability is $\frac{25}{100}$ for each?
2. If you then draw an items of type '$a$' out of then bag, how does this effect the probabilities?
3. What if you then draw out an item of type '$b$'?

Thanks

Edit: 
I think i'm looking for something like Josu Etxezarreta Martinez answer.

Additional follow up questions:

4. does $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ mean you are more likely to draw an 'a' on the next draw compared to a 'd' when $P(d)= \frac{\#d-1}{99}$?
5. if on a third iteration I again selected an 'a', would that make $P(a)= \frac{\#a-2}{97}$?

Comment: For the first, clearly not.  Maybe there are $97$ of type $a$ and $1$ each of types $b,c,d$.

Comment: Ok, so how would you find the probability of drawing each type of item after each draw? Sorry if this is all very simple. I really suck at mathematics.

Comment: You can't do much of anything unless you know the initial proportions.  Qualitatively, if you remove an $a$ from the pool then the probability that the next is an $a$ goes down (unless they were all of type $a$).

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a way of making predictions of the distribution of each item after each draw based on what has been drawn?

Comment: Well, maybe.  But that's a pretty general question.   And it helps a lot to have some prior notion of what the distribution is likely to be.  I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, would you possible be able to provide any answers with my questions in the comment thread of Josu Etxezarreta Martinez's answer?

Comment: I think a correct answer to this question is to use Bayesian inference: start out with a guess about the distribution (you suggest a uniform distribution) and update your guess each time you get new information. I've no time to post this comment as an answer. Read about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference

Comment: If you have additional questions, you should just create a new question. You already have an answer for the first few, so another answer will have to be added for the new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question you are assuming that there are 25 elements of each of the items in the bag. The actualk real distribution would be:

$P(x_i)=\frac{\#x_i}{100}$ where $\sum_i\#x_i=100$, and where $\#$ denotes number of elements.

For the second and third question you must use the same method, but when taking out an item of an specific kind you should rest one to the number of items in that specific group and also one to the total amount of elements in the bag, that would be

(b) $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ $P(b)= \frac{\#b}{99}$ $P(c)= \frac{\#c}{99}$ $P(d)= \frac{\#d}{99}$

(c) $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{98}$ $P(b)= \frac{\#b-1}{98}$ $P(c)= \frac{\#c}{98}$ $P(d)= \frac{\#d}{98}$

Comment: Ok. Could this be generalized to an unknown amount in the bag by replacing the 100 with N for instance?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok great. Also, if on a third iteration I again selected an 'a', would that make $P(a)= \frac{\#a-2}{97}$ ?

Comment: Also, does $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ mean you are more likely to draw out an 'a' rather than a 'd' when $P(d)= \frac{\#d}{99}$ ?

Comment: The first is correct. For the second one it would depend on nubers $\#a$ and $\#d$, the result that would be more likely would be the one with higher probability, so if $P(a)>P(d)$ then $a$ is more likely while if $P(a)<P(d)$ then $d$ would be more likely.

Comment: Ok, but give that #a and #d and currently unknown does that mean you cannot say which is more probable until you know #a and #d? and wouldn't this only be known when all items in the bag are known?

Comment: Yes, if you want to know which os the most probable outcome you must know the probability distribution which in this case is given by those numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help. I think I'm understanding this now. Final question, could you say then, that the probability of selecting an 'a' on the next draw is less when $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ compared to when $P(a)= \frac{\#a-2}{98}$

Comment: I would tell so. You can try to prove it.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Thanks for all your help Josu Etxezarreta Martinez.